# ASP.NET Core System.Runtime not found on test

Tags: asp.net, powershell, .net-core, xunit, opencover

Been trying to run ASP.NET Core 1.1 xunit tests coverage from PowerShell with no success. When running I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
>   .

On PowerShell line (the last one):

```
$solutionDir = "C:\Projects\AdministrationPortal.RestAPI"
$openCoverDir = (Get-ChildItem $packagesDir -filter "OpenCover*" -Directory | % { $_.fullname })
$openCoverRunner = "$openCoverDir\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe"

$packagesDir = $solutionDir + "\packages"
$xunitRunnerDir =  (Get-ChildItem $packagesDir -filter "xunit.runner.console*" -Directory | % { $_.fullname })
$xunitRunner = "$xunitRunnerDir\tools\xunit.console.exe"

$unitTestsProjDir = (Get-ChildItem $solutionDir\test -filter "*Test*" -    Directory | % { $_.fullname })
$testsDllDir = "$unitTestsProjDir\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1"
$testDllFile = (Get-ChildItem $testsDllDir -File |  Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*Test*.dll" -and $_.Name -notlike "*xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter*" } ) 
$testDll = "$testsDllDir\$testDllFile"

$categories = "Integration;Unit"
$nameSpaceToTest = "AdminPortal.RestAPI.Areas.FeatureToggle.Services;AdminPortal.RestAPI.Areas.FeatureToggle.Storage;AdminPortal.RestAPI.Areas.Text.Services;AdminPortal.RestAPI.Areas.Text.Storage"
$nameSpaceToSkip = ""
$assemblyToTest = "AdminPortal.RestAPI"
$categoriesArray = (($categories -split ';') | ? {$_})
$nameSpaceToTestArray = (($nameSpaceToTest -split ';') | ? {$_})
$nameSpaceToSkipArray = (($nameSpaceToSkip -split ';') | ? {$_})

ForEach ($item In $nameSpaceToTestArray) {
$nameSpaceArray += "+[$assemblyToTest*]" + $item + "* " }

ForEach ($item In $nameSpaceToSkipArray) {
$nameSpaceArray += "-[$assemblyToTest*]" + $item + "* " }
$coverageReportDir = "C:\tmp\Coverage"

foreach ($item in $categoriesArray) {
    $coverageReportXML = $coverageReportDir + "\coverage." + $item + ".xml"
    Write-Output $coverageReportXML
    & $openCoverRunner -register:user -target:"$xunitRunner" "-targetargs:$testDll" -targetdir:"$testsDllDir"  -output:"$coverageReportXML" "-filter:$nameSpaceArray"
}
```

The initial thought was that .NET Framework 4.6 does not have System.Runtime but then I added additional framework imports that do have it, yet the results are the same. project.json file of the test project:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "xunit",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.1.0"
    },
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta5-build3474",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.2.0-beta3-build1187",
    "Moq": "4.6.38-alpha",
    "System.Linq": "4.3.0",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions": "1.0.0",
    "OpenCover": "4.6.519",
    "ReportGenerator": "2.5.2",
    "Microsoft.CodeCoverage": "1.0.2",
    "xunit.runner.console": "2.2.0-beta5-build3474",
    "System.Runtime": "4.3.0",
    "AdminPortal.RestAPI": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net46"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: question aside: why you are using xunitRunner instead of dotnet test ?

Comment: tried both, result is the same